# Symfony logging not saving history after rotating logfile

Tags: php, logging, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have this setup in my symfony application:

```
# settings.yml
prod:
  .settings:
    no_script_name:         true
    logging_enabled:        true

#logging.yml
prod:
  enabled: on
  level:   debug
  rotate:  on
  period:  1       ## Log files are rotated every 1 day
  history: 30      ## A maximum history of 30 log files is kept
  purge:   off
```

But I only find one file (frontend_prod.log) in my logs dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are indeed using 1.4, I don't think log rotation from the settings file isn't supported any more. You should use the `log:rotate` task from the CLI (in a cron tab perhaps), and use the `--history` and `--period` options.